# Is there any way to use facebook login on a localhost?

Tags: mysql, authentication, facebook-php-sdk

I am new to web development, I've learned php, mysql and javascript. I'm trying to make a website that uses facebook authentication and login. At the moment, I'm still working on localhost and am running xxamp. Is there any way to use the facebook development tools on a localhost? Or would it be simpler if I made my own mysql user database?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need mysql to use the php-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook [authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) working same way in local environment as it working in every other place (just configure application using local URL's for "Canvas URL" and/or "Site URL"). To achieve this you may use both [PHP-SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) and [JS-SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) for that. See [examples for PHP-SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/tree/master/examples) how-to implement authentication of user.

There is however functionality like social channels for which you'll need that Facebook be able to reach the machine your app running on (this may be solved with a bit of effort too)...